# Eclipse JUNIT: Why is it possible to sometimes do a compare on a failed assertequals(String,String) but not always

Tags: eclipse, junit

I thought at first the compare option only appears for a test if the assertequals is between 2 strings, which makes sense. I believe i have also fired a failNotEquals(String1,String2) and the compare option comes up as well. I have done this when the object does not implement equals or perhaps i wish to compare for equality using my own rules and failing if that fails. However i have noticed a few times here and there sometimes failNotequals(String,String) does not enable the "compare" option. Am i missing something ???

CLARIFICATION of COMPARE option
The >compare< option is a menu option that is available when one right clicks on a failed junit item from the gui where it creates a tree with items for each "test". Often theres also a >print stack trace< option.

Answer (score 2):

You get the "compare" option, when the end result of the test is a *junit.framework.ComparisonFailure* object. In that case you can see a visual comparison of the two objects (Strings for example) and check how they differ from each other.

Other types of results, such as a *java.lang.IllegalAccessError*, aren't parsed to that effect, as Eclipse doesn't know (and cannot deduce) that you were comparing two objects that lead to such a result, so it doesn't offer you the same visual boons.

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure what you mean by

> failNotEquals does not enable the "compare" option

Here are a couple of thoughts.

1. failNotEquals takes three arguments, not two:

   failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
2. Even if strings would print out the same, they are NOT the same object. You need to tell JUnit how to compare them.

Consider this small, working test case.

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class DemoTest extends TestCase {
  public void testSomething() {
    String a = "Hello";
    assertTrue("Strings should be the same", "Hello".equals(a));
    failNotEquals("Strings should be the same", "Hello", a);
  }
}
```

The assertTrue works, but the failNotEquals does not.

The assertTrue is probably what you want. The `"Hello".equals(a)` will compare the strings properly. You can also use a `equalsIgnoreCase` here.

I'm guessing that the failNotEquals is probably close to what you are using. It fails with a `java.lang.IllegalAccessError`.

Comment: Actually your choice of using asssertTrue is a poor choice because if the test fails it doesnt include what the *wrong* string is which is why you should use assertequals simply because it shows the expected and the actual. You commentary about using asserttrue is crap - a better choice would be if( a.equalsIgnoreCase(b)) { failNotequals("message goes here", a, b ), again it shows the difference with a meaningful message.

Comment: I have no idea you have raised point #2. If you read my q, it clearly says i do the comparison my self and then invoke failNotequals if the test fails. assertEquals() does exactly the same thing.